# Using tree sort to modify array

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am looking to use tree sort in order to store the numbers sorted in an array as opposed to just outputting the numbers in a sorted order. n is initialized to zero.

```
void BinSearchTree::inOrder( TreeNodePtr subRoot, int A[], int n )
{
    if ( subRoot != NULL )             
    {
        inOrder( subRoot->left, A, n );    

        A[n] = subRoot->key;
        n++;

        inOrder( subRoot->right, A, n ); 
    }
}
```

I believe the problem lies where I continue to call A as a parameter for inOrder but I don't know how else I would do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a reference to n, otherwise you can't know what is the next element to assign, that is:

```
void BinSearchTree::inOrder( TreeNodePtr subRoot, int A[], int& last )
{
    if ( subRoot != NULL )             
    {
        inOrder( subRoot->left, A, n );    

        A[last++] = subRoot->key;

        inOrder( subRoot->right, A, n ); 
    }
}
```

Other option would be to use a container with a push_back function like a vector:

```
 void BinSearchTree::inOrder( TreeNodePtr subRoot, std::vector<int>& vec )
    {
        if ( subRoot != NULL )             
        {
            inOrder( subRoot->left, vec );    

            vec.push_back( subRoot->key );

            inOrder( subRoot->right, vec); 
        }
    }
```